# Infinite sum of reciprocals of positive integers convergent to some rational number in a given range

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rational-numbers

I am looking for an example of some infinite sum of reciprocals of positive integers convergent to some rational number in the range $(1,2)$.

I am also interested in methods to construct such infinite sums convergent to rational numbers in the range stated, if available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest using Geometric series.  For instance, $\sum_0^{\infty}2^{-n}=2$ so just delete any term other than the first to get in the right range.

Comment: As another approach:  pick your favorite rational number between $1$ and $2$, and write it in base $2$ (or base $10$ for that matter).

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n} =\frac{4}{3}$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_of_the_Parabola

Comment: Remark:  to use the base $10$ decimal, you could just repeat summands (you did not specify that the summands be distinct).  Thus a term like $\frac 3{100}$ becomes $\frac 1{100}+\frac 1{100}+\frac 1{100}$.   But if you use base $2$ then the summands are automatically distinct.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comments! I someone wants to share an answer, happy to upvote and accept it